# Numbers are not correctly added up

Tags: javascript

I want to compute some number for each given day. The actual number does not matter, it should just be somewhat different but it must be stable.

So I have done the following so far:

```
now = new Date();

begin_of_week = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() - now.getDay() + 1);

for (idx in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) {
    seed = parseInt(idx)
        + begin_of_week.getFullYear() * 400,
        + begin_of_week.getMonth() * 31,
        + begin_of_week.getDate();

    // ...
}
```

I expect that this gives me some `seed` for each day of the week from Monday to Friday. However, I different numbers for the days, but I now have the same numbers as last week.

JavaScript's type system is a mystery to me. I would expect that all those are `int` and they just get added up. It makes a difference whether I put the `idx` at the beginning or the end of the chain. And the `parseInt`, which should do nothing, actually changes the results.

What is going on here? How can I just add those numbers?

Comment: You should not need `parseInt` here. You should [not use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: Ouch, the `for ... in` makes the loop variable a string. This explains it, of course!

Comment: Also an issue are the stray commas after `400` and `31`. I don't know how they got there, but this of course also is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I expect that this gives me some seed for each day of the week from
>   Monday to Friday. However, I different numbers for the days, but I now
>   have the same numbers as last week.

This is because your `begin_of_week` is going to be same for entire week as you have given

```
now.getDate() - now.getDay() + 1
```

which essentially ensures that your date parameter is always **offset'ed by number of days passed already in the week**.

> I would expect that all those are int and they just get added up.

You are **assigning the value to seed** rather than incrementing the `seed` value by the other values, so this is as good as

```
seed = parseInt(4)
        + begin_of_week.getFullYear() * 400,
        + begin_of_week.getMonth() * 31,
        + begin_of_week.getDate();
```

If you want to keep incrementing `seed` value, then use `+=` instead of `=`

Comment: I explicitly add the `idx` to the `seed` in order to get something different for each day in the week. I don't see the need for `+=`.

Comment: Your idx value doesn't vary for each day of the week.

Comment: My `idx` value *is* the day of the week. Perhaps the misunterstanding is this: I want to generate five pseudo-random numbers that are stable within a week. These five numbers are meant for the five working days in the week. In the next work-week, I want five new numbers.

Comment: Your comment above is a much better description of a problem than your question. If you want a new number every day then use `now` instead of `begin_of_week` in your calculation.